# Remove blank rows between data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula or vba code that will remove the blank rows in column B between them and joining them on column D. Look at the pic for reference.

[image]

Comment: A formula will never work as it cannot affect other cells. Do you mean a subroutine? What have you tried so far? Remember that SO is not a code writing service but rather a forum to get targeted help on specific coding errors.

Comment: @nbayly I think OP is wanting the formula(s) to reside in column D and E that read the data from Column A and B, respectively but ignore the blanks.

Comment: @JNevill exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula approach. Enter this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$800, SMALL(IF(($B$1:$B$800)="", "", ROW($B$1:$B$800)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$800))+1), ROW(A1))),"")
```

in cell `E1` and drag it to down. You must enter it using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER since it is an array formula.

Then enter this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($B$1:$B$800)="","",ROW($B$1:$B$800)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$800))+1),ROW(A1)),0)),"")
```

in cell `D1` and also drag it to the bottom. This is also array formula so you need to confirm it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER combination.

[image]

Comment: it's not working for me, i should tell you, in those blanks are actually formulas which in terms are blank, not sure if that will effect the formula.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include formula values, it should work now.

Comment: I have another problem, what if example 1 and example 2 both have the same item such as Dog? Lets say both Example 1 and Example 2 have only one item but have the same thing, How would it distinguish both?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:E200").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B200").Value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:E200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:E200").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:E200").Value  
End Sub
```

Comment: i cannot have it shift up or right, it has to state static.

Comment: Why don't you paste the values in another sheet and then copy the cells from there.Added one line the code for same.If required you can delete the values from temporary sheet or delete the sheet itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this little bit of code a number of times to delete blank lines in reports.  It will find the last row with data in column "A" and delete the row if there is nothing in it.

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Do While lastRow >= 1
If Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "" Then Rows(lastRow).Delete
lastRow = lastRow - 1
Loop
```

Comment: cannot delete rows. all rows has to stay.